# C# Can I use a int declared in the main() in a extern bool?

Tags: c#, boolean

So, I was trying to make a program that given three numbers, the one that i one to see if it's between the other two and the other two, says if the first number is between the others.

I wanted to do so with a outside the main() program bool, but when i try to call the variables declarated in the main says "The name 'a' does not exist in the current context"

Is there any way to use a int declared in main in a extern boolean?
My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("number to check");
        int a; a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("1st range");
        int rang1; rang1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("2n range:");
        int rang2; rang2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (EnRang() = true) { Console.WriteLine("Number {0} is between {1} and {2}", a, rang1, rang2); }
        else if (EnRang() = false)
        { Console.WriteLine("The number {0} isn't between {1} and {2}", a, rang1, rang2); }
        else { Console.WriteLine("Something goes wrong."); }
    }

    public static bool EnRang()
    {
        int NumerBool = a; int RangA = rang1; int RangB = rang2;
        if (a > RangA || a < RangB){ return true; }
        else{ return false; }
    }

}
```

Comment: try passing `a`, `rang1` and `rang2` as parameters to the `EnRang` method. [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters)

Comment: It seems that you need to learn about _scope_ of variables

Comment: If you want to compare values, you need an == (doubled)

Comment: When EnRang can return only true or false, you don't need to test again in an else-if

Comment: @HansKeﬆing about the ==, sorry, i forget it. Also thanks for the advice on the bool

Comment: I guess you need && instead of || as the value should be between the limits

Comment: You can declare and assign variables on a single line: `int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you pointed in the right direction. You need to pass the variables as parameters to you `EnRang` method.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("number to check");
        int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("1st range");
        int rang1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("2n range:");
        int rang2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (EnRang(a, rang1, rang2) == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number {0} is between {1} and {2}", a, rang1, rang2);
        }
        else if (EnRang(a, rang1, rang2) == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The number {0} isn't between {1} and {2}", a, rang1, rang2);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something goes wrong.");
        }
    }

    public static bool EnRang(int NumerBool, int RangA, int RangB)
    {

        if (NumerBool > RangA && NumerBool < RangB)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's ok as an OR, will leave it to the op to decide :)

Comment: Checked the logic and you are right. Updated the answer.